# Grails data binding- command objects with Maps

Tags: grails, object, command

Grails 2.0.3

I am having problem with binding the data to command objects. I have the jquery request like this
http://localhost:8080/api/test.json?callback=jQuery17102313091890902648_1334273415631&ex[0][a]=a0&ex[0][b]=b0&ex[1][a]=a1&ex[1][b]=b1

I need a way of binding the data from the request url to command object. Something like this

```
class TestCommand
{
    List<Map<String, String>> ex
    static constraints = {}
}
```

I wanted to bind the data dynamically so that I can get ex[0].a = a0 and ex[0].b = b0 and use it in the controller directly. This is working fine for list. But, not working for list of maps. Is there any way to bind data like this

Answer (score 1):

have you tried using [bindData](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/bindData.html)?

after all, it doesn't matter how you make your request (by using jQuery or a conventional GET method) the thing is resolved server-side.